# Magento2: Get product date in Knockout Js

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, knockoutjs

How to get special delivery end date in ko js

I have implemented KO templated with Js How can I get Value of Product Special delivery date in JS for countdown

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="new.ko.component" template="SilkSoftware_ProductCountdown::newko-component.phtml" before="product.info.details" />
    </referenceContainer>
```

newko-component.phtml

```
<div id="m2-component" data-bind="scope:'m2kocomponent'">
    <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#m2-component": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "m2kocomponent": {
                        "component": "SilkSoftware_ProductCountdown/js/m2kocomponent",
                        "template" : "SilkSoftware_ProductCountdown/m2kocomponent-template"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

js

```
define(['jquery', 'uiComponent', 'ko'], function ($, Component, ko) {
    'use strict';

    var self;
    return Component.extend({
        myTimer: ko.observable(0),
        initialize: function () {
            self = this;
            this._super();
            //call the incrementTime function to run on intialize
            this.incrementTime();
        },
        //increment myTimer every second
        incrementTime: function() {

             var futureDate = new Date("11/23/2018").getTime();

             self.myTimer(Date.parse(new Date());
                  }     }); });
```

and .html

```
<div class="component-wrapper">
    <div data-bind="text: 'Catalog Timer'"></div>
     <div data-bind="text: myTimer"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
<div id="m2-component" data-bind="scope:'ko'">
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#m2-component": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
               "components": {
                    "ko": {
                        "component": "SilkSoftware_ProductCountdown/js/m2kocomponent",
                        "template" : "SilkSoftware_ProductCountdown/m2kocomponent-template"
                        "specialDateEnd": <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $specialDateEnd ?>
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

**js**

```
define(['uiComponent', 'ko'], function (Component, ko) {

return Component.extend({
    initialize: function (config) {
        var self = this;
        this._super();
        console.log(config.specialDateEnd);
    },
});
```

You can assign this value in any var and use it in your template file. Let me know if any further help needed.

Comment: Did my answer help you @paras ?

Comment: Not actually, because the variable in .phtml will be cached, and what if we need to update it?